# Excel - Static/Unchangeable filters

Tags: excel, filtering

In Excel 2013, assume I have a set of data on vehicles.  It contains information about cars, tracks, and motorcycles.  This info is year, color, engine size, etc.  I want to make 3 separate pivot charts.  One chart is JUST about cars, one JUST about trucks, one chart JUST about motorcycles.  The other attributes can be filterable/pivot fields, but I want each of the 3 separate charts to contains JUST that vehicle type.  I know I COULD have one pivot field on the vehicle type, and just preset it to Car/truck/motorcycle for each of the 3 charts, but I would really like a "static/unchangeable" filter for each of the 3 charts.  Ideally, I would like it so that user doesn't even see a filter/selection for vehicle type on the pivot chart. Does Excel support this capability?

Comment: Just hide filter buttons from pivot chart

Comment: @bzimor - I would expect the property to be called 'Visible', but that is not working.  Any idea what the property name is called? It specifically would be for a PageField on a PivotTable.

Comment: See: http://blog.contextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/FilterChart02.png